# Can you have function pointer with assigned parameter value in C?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I want to point to something like `add(2, 1)` and then call it without needing to specify parameters. Is there some way to do this with function pointers?

Comment: Succinctly — no.

Comment: No, alas not (well, not unless you wanted to implement a whole object orientated framework in C which has been done). You could do this in C++ though.

Comment: Make a wrapper. Then point to it.

Comment: Are you asking strictly out of curiosity? If not, this sounds a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).. is there a more general task you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Read wikipage about [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))s

Comment: Well, I am trying to map op codes to functions, and there are lot of them which I could reuse with different argument values. Just asking if there is better solution then making for each op code separate function without parameters containing my function with arguments.

Comment: Then consider  the `switch/case` approach.

Comment: Create a binary operator function type, then an `add` function can be of that type.

Comment: I thing I will stick with wrapper solution. Thanks.

Comment: [There is a proposal to add this feature to the next version of C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2030.pdf), but it isn't directly supported in the language yet.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As a comment to your question, [Basile Starynkevitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841108/basile-starynkevitch) suggested reading about [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). At its core, a closure combines a function to be called with some context, referred to in the literature as the function’s *environment*.

Object-oriented languages have a similar concept known as [delegates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_(object-oriented_programming)) where a particular instance can become the environment for a later call where the calling site has no direct knowledge of the underlying object. Languages that support closures natively automatically capture or “close over” the bindings provided in the environment. It may seem an odd language feature, but it can be expressive and useful as the motivation behind your question suggests.

Below is a simple example of the concept of a closure at work in a C program, where it is up to the programmer to direct the captures explicitly.

The function you want to eventually call plus some front matter is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
add_two_numbers(int a, int b)
{
  return a+b;
}
```

A closure is a function to be called combined with its environment. In C, the function to be called is a *pointer to function*. Note that the parameters of `f` align with those of `add_two_numbers`.

```
typedef struct {
  struct {  /* environment */
    int a;
    int b;
  } env;

  int (*f)(int, int);  /* function to be called */
} closure;
```

We’d like to create a closure, *i.e.*, set up the association of parameter values to pass with the function to be called when we are ready to do so. In this simple example, `make_adder` leaves the problem of allocating space for the closure to its caller.

```
void
make_adder(int a, int b, closure *c)
{
  c->env.a = a;
  c->env.b = b;
  c->f = add_two_numbers;
}
```

Now that you know how to create one of our simple closures, you call or *invoke* it as in

```
int invoke_closure(closure *c)
{
  return c->f(c->env.a, c->env.b);
}
```

Finally, usage will look like

```
int main(void)
{
  closure c;
  make_adder(2, 1, &c);

  printf("The answer is %d.\n", invoke_closure(&c));

  return 0;
}
```

with output of

```
The answer is 3.
```

#### Further Reading

- [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)
- [Partial Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application)

Comment: Some people call a closely related technique in C the baton. So if you see `void * baton` that's what it is.

Comment: @Joshua I often see cbdata or userdata or similar.

Answer (score 9):

While the short answer is "no", there are ways to accomplish what you want to do.

The first thing to remember is that `add` needs two parameters. No matter what you do, you have to provide it the two parameters.

The second thing to remember is that if you want to call a function that ultimately calls `add(2, 1)`, you have to have stored or hard coded the values `2` and `1` somewhere so that they can be used.

There are couple of ways to do that that I can think of.

1. Create a wrapper function that calls `add(2, 1)` and let your code call the wrapper function.

   ```
   int add2And1()
   {
      return add(2, 1);
   }
   ```

   and then use `add2And1` in your call.
2. Create a wrapper function that relies on global data. Set the global data first before using the wrapper function.

   ```
   int param1 = 0;
   int param2 = 0;


   int addParams()
   {
      return add(param1, param2);
   }
   ```

   and then use:

   ```
   param1 = 2;
   param2 = 1;
   ```

   in your code before calling `addParams`.

Comment: I'd really encourage option #1. #2 and the use of global variables are more flexible, but have their own set of nightmares associated (mostly hard-to-find side effects).

Answer (score 6):

```
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

No you canno't have a pointer to `add` with assigned parameter values for it. However you can do this:

```
int add_2_1() { return add(2, 1); }
```

however I don't see how helpful is this...

Answer (score 1):

A GCC extension will let you do this:

```
int func(int addend, int (*next)(int (*f2)(int))
{
    int add(int addend2) { return addend + addend2; }
    next(add);
}
```

However if you try to do:

```
int (*)(int) func(int addend)
{
    int add(int addend2) { return addend + addend2; }
    return add;
}
```

the function cannot be used because `func(3)(3)` executes a trampoline* on the stack that has already been freed. This is pretty much the most undefined behavior there is.

*A trampoline is a small piece of code that immediately jumps to another piece of code. In this case the trampoline looks something like

```
mov rax, 0xfuncstackframeaddress
mov r10, rax
lea rax, [func.add]
jmp rax
```

Of course there's lots of ways of doing this and it doesn't matter which one GCC uses. GCC is solving the problem of how to pass a parameter with a function pointer by writing dynamic code. No matter what code was written there, the next time function call depth gets deep enough the stack frame will be overwritten.

Comment: "executes a trampoline" -- could you explain what that means?